# why Configuration: Subsystems Subsystem: Logging with Wildfly filter give Error and not trace

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Why evertime went to Configuration: Subsystems Subsystem: Logging within Wildfly and define a filter or give Error or does not trace in the specify file? There is any good regex pattern for filter logging or good pratices?

```
Failed to modify resource [ ("subsystem" => "logging"), ("logger" => "com.api.services.atendance") ]

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "operation" => "composite",
    "address" => [],
    "steps" => [{
        "address" => [
            ("subsystem" => "logging"),
            ("logger" => "com.api.services.atendance")
        ],
        "operation" => "write-attribute",
        "name" => "filter-spec",
        "value" => "com.api.services.atendance"
    }]
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "result" => {"step-1" => {
        "outcome" => "failed",
        "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected identifier next in filter expression",
        "rolled-back" => true
    }},
    "failure-description" => {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected identifier next in filter expression"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Periodic Handler
definition with:

```
         <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="Atendance">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
            <filter-spec value="match(&quot;atendance&quot;)"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="atendance.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

LOG CATEGORIES with Logger definition as:

```
<logger category="org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation" use-parent-handlers="true">
    <level name="ERROR"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="Atendance"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Comment: `Expected identifier next in filter expression` your CLI command is malformed

Comment: The `value` attribute in your request looks incorrect. How are you attempting to change the `filter-spec`?